# onTouchEvent() based on touch position

Tags: android, surfaceview, drawtext

In my `SurfaceView`, I have the following method.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        if ((motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // ... do something
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I would like the code response could depend on point where I touch. For example, in the canvas, I have some `canvas.drawText()` and for each of them, I would like to have different actions.

Comment: by action you mean execute some fun, or motion event actions ?

Comment: @P.Juni well I mean a sort of switch statement: if I click on a certain drawText(), the code does something. If I click to another drawText(), the code does something else.

Comment: ok, but point where you touch means, that if you place your finger under certain x/y coords some `drawText()` will execute ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
private View.OnTouchListener handleTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.i("TAG", "touched down");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.i("TAG", "moving: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.i("TAG", "touched up");
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
};
```

THen set the view

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(handleTouch);
```